# Convert a sysdate() into int datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `sysdate() value - 2016.10.18`. I need a **SQL** to convert it to `int` in **MS SQL SERVER**.

> INPUT - 2016.10.18 
>   OUTPUT reqd. - 20161018

I tried this -

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, '2016.10.18')
```

but it throws the following error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2016.10.18' to data type int.

Also tried this -

```
select  CONVERT(int,CONVERT(decimal(19,2),'2016.10.18'))
```

Getting the following error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Could someone help me out!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Convert(int,Convert(varchar,cast('2016.10.18' as date),112))
```

Returns

```
20161018
```

Either of the following will work.  If you have a use the replace() method, you will need to strip the time portion off via LEFT(...,10)

```
Select Convert(int,Convert(varchar,cast('2016.10.18 14:24:49' as date),112))
Select cast(Replace(Left('2016.10.18 14:24:49',10),'.','') as int)
```

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(int,REPLACE('2016.10.18','.','')) - Will this work? I did get the required ouput through this SQL too.

Comment: @Dilip Yes provided Jan 18, 2016 is NOT represented as 2016.1.18

Comment: @Dilip  You may get a FALSE POSITIVE / conversion if your data is not uniform or complete i.e.  2016.10

Comment: I am running the SQL through SAP Data Services. So the sysdate generated by SAP is in this format - 2016.10.18 14:24:49. I actually need to convert this format into 20161018

Comment: @Dilip See second portion of my answer

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer.

```
Select Cast(Convert(varchar(8), Cast(Left('2016.10.18 14:24:49',10) as Date), 112) as int)
```

Comment: This would work if the string was a date or even a date format, otherwise you get a conversion error   ---  Select Cast(Convert(varchar(8),'2016.10.18', 112) as int)

Comment: I running the SQL through SAP Data Services. So the sysdate generated by SAP is in this format - 2016.10.18 14:24:49. I actually need to convert this format into 20161018